# How to delete https://sitename.com/sitename page on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url

My website is https://webovane.com/
When I check website on GTMetrix. I see https://webovane.com/webovane.com url in Waterfall. And this is slowing down my website. I tried redirect but i don't want to redirect this page to my main page. I want to delete permanently.
How do i delete this?

Comment: It's hard for anyone to help you if you don’t provide any code or examples. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: How can i help you without any minimum information ?

Comment: I solved, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to the following code:

`<script>if(navigator.userAgent.match(/x11.*fox\/54|x11.*ome\/39|x11.*ome\/62|oobot|ighth|tmetr|eadles/i)){document.write("<script defer type=text\/javascript src=webovane.com><\/script>");}else{document.write("<script type=text\/javascript src=https:\/\/webovane.com\/wp-content\/cache\/fvm\/1558601149\/out\/header-84e60a2d.min.js><\/script>");}</script>`

When this writes `<script defer type=text/javascript src=webovane.com></script>` into the document, this causes a request to `https://webovane.com/webovane.com` - because `src=webovane.com` is referring to a *relative* URL, since it is missing a protocol.

---

Now I can’t tell you where this script comes from in the first place - whether that is part of your template, added by some plugin, … and neither whether this is something that can be fixed via configuration (URL for this script specified wrong somewhere maybe), or needs to be adjusted in some template file. And what the *correct* JavaScript URL to load in this case would be, is unknown as well.